# Scanning Items in DynamoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, amazon-dynamodb, dispatch-async

I am trying to scan for a tagItems containing a substring from a search bar. Whenever the text changes this search method is initiated in my Data Access Object. The notification then tells my ViewController to reload my tableView which displays all the search results. It works fine when I add break points, however when it runs without breaks it does not show any of the results for a minute but it will nslog that array has the proper items and that the table is being reloaded. Then a warning will appear in the console and the results will pop up long after they were received. This is the warning: This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.  From what I gather it usually means dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}); needs to be added somewhere but I cannot understand why. I am trying to constantly reload the tableView. Here is my code:

```
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
scanExpression.limit = [NSNumber numberWithInt:25];
scanExpression.filterExpression = @"contains(tagName, :val)";
scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{
                                             @":val":searchText,
                                             };

[[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[AWSTopicObject class]
                 expression:scanExpression]
 continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error.description);
     }
     if (task.exception) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
     }
     if (task.result) {
         AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
         NSLog(@"%@",paginatedOutput.items);
         for(AWSTagObject *tag in paginatedOutput.items){
             NSString *tempTag = tag.tagName;
             [self.searchArray addObject:tempTag];
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
              postNotificationName:@"SearchNotification"
              object:self];
         }
     }
     return nil;
 }];
```

Comment: Unless your table has a really small number of items in it you should not be doing a table scan as it will be expensive, have bad performance, and not scale.

Comment: @JaredHatfield is it possible to add an index to tag name and query for values containing the substring?

Comment: The bad practice of scanning aside, it sounds like the problem you are having is not caused by Dynamo but by doing work on the main thread from a background thread - that is an IOS issue.